# Getting cells address from value in phpEXcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the PHPExcel library to read an Excel file and perform processing on it.
I have some doubt regarding fetching of celladdress.

#### Sample of excel:

id  | Name   |  Age
191 | Seller |  25
192 | Buyer  |  69
193 | Amith  |  40

I need to fetch the cell address of value 'Buyer'.
I knew that its under the header 'Name' and whose id is 192.
Can any one please help me to fetch the cell address...

Comment: You'd have to iterate through the top row to find which cell in that row contained the value 'Name', look at the column id for that cell, then iterate through all the cells in that column until you found the cell that contained value 'Buyer'.... there's no magic that will do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$cell_coordinates = '';

foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    $row_number = $row->getRowIndex();

    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        $cellValue = $cell->getCalculatedValue();

        if($cellValue === 'Buyer' && $row_number === 192) {
            $cell_coordinates = $cell->getColumn() . '192';
        }
    }
}
```